# .height() doesn't work in WebKit

Tags: javascript, jquery, dom

My code is supposed to get the height of several items in a div. It works like a charm in Firefox, but in WebKit the is no height().

```
for (var i = 0; i < items.length; i++) {
  var item = items[i];
  var itemHeight;
  var itemWidth;
  var imageItem = $($(item).find('.teaser_image'));

  itemWidth = imageItem.width();

  if (itemWidth > this.imageWidth()) {
    imageItem.width(this.imageWidth());
  }

  // TODO: Height-thingy works in Firefox but not in WebKit.
  itemHeight = imageItem.height();

}
```

The strange thing is that the `imageItem` object is correct in WebKit and Firefox. But if I use `.height()` on it, it is 0 in WebKit. 
The used jQuery Version is 1.7.2 and can not be changed.

Comment: try this

`itemHeight = parseInt(imageItem.css('height'));`

Comment: Be sure your images have been loaded

Comment: You might get this if your code is wrapped in "$(document).ready(...)". This will bulletproof work with "$(window).load(...)"

Comment: probably a related problem: [image height using jquery in chrome problem](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1743880/image-height-using-jquery-in-chrome-problem)

Comment: Juuro try  var imageItem = $(item).find('.teaser_image');

Answer (score 0):

This works for me http://jsfiddle.net/z6bYp/1/

```
<script>
var imageItem = $('.teaser_image');
alert(imageItem.height());
</script>
```

Be sure to find something when you define imageItem, use the debugger

```
for (var i = 0; i < items.length; i++) {

  var imageItem = $($(item).find('.teaser_image'));
```