# Is it so bad to have heaps of elements in your DOM?

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-chrome, jcarousel

[I am making a real estate non interactive display for their shop window](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3050111/attention-javascript-gurus-need-a-hand-with-setinterval/3050200#3050200).

I have kicked [jCarousel](http://sorgalla.com/projects/jcarousel) into doing what I want:

- Add panels per AJAX
- Towards the end of the current set, go and AJAX some new panels and insert them

This works fine, but it appears calling jQuery's `remove()` on the prior elements cause an ugly bump. I'm not sure if calling `hide()` will free up any resources, as the element will still exist (and the element will be off screen anyway).

I've seen [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2645980/removing-an-item-from-jcarousel-plug-in), and tried `carousel.reset()` from within a callback. It just clears out all the elements.

This will be running on Google Chrome on Windows XP, and will solely be displaying on LCD televisions.

I am wondering, if I *can't* find a reasonable solution to remove the extra DOM elements, will it bring my application to a crawl, or will Chrome do some clever garbage collecting?

Or, how would *you* solve this problem?

Thanks

Comment: How many elements are we talking about here?  If they have no data cleanup is quicker, if they have data/handlers (which you can avoid by using delegate or live) it is a bit different, in terms of what's most efficient.

Comment: @Nick Craver Thanks for stopping by. If you look at the link in the previous question, you'll see how I implemented the *adding* of new items to jCarousel. I use its own `add()` method. However, if I do a `$('#listing li:lt(5)').remove()` or similar to clean up, it bumps the list up to fill the gap where the previous list items were. Perhaps I could loop through the first 10 or so every AJAX request, get the total height, then set the ul's `padding-top` to be that height (and remove the ones that were in the space). Sounds clunky though. I hope you can offer me a better solution! Thanks again.

Answer (score 1):

Could you reuse old elements instead of removing them and adding new ones ?

Comment: Maybe, but I am using a third party jQuery plugin an am unsure of how to get it to do that. Do you have any suggestions?

Answer (score 1):

I worked out a fix that ended up being very simple!

Simply pass this to the config for jCarousel

```
itemFirstOutCallback: {
               onAfterAnimation: function(carousel, li, index, state) {
                 if (state === 'init') return;

                 carousel.remove(index); 

               }
            }
```

Basically, this just removes the list element as soon as it becomes invisible (scrolled into negative `overflow: hidden` territory, if you will :)  )